# VS2015 not compatible with dotnet-core cli

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, .net-core

I cannot make VS2015 work with `dotnet cli` - I would like to edit and test may dotnet-core project using VS2015 and then have the ability to compile & run it using dotnet cli. However all my attempts to make it so were not successful, which is not ideal - I am aming for writing code on Windows and then using Travis-Ci for bulding.

So this is what is happening:

#### VS2015 -> Dotnet cli

If I create VS2015 “Console Application” Project (Target .Net Framework 4.6.1) for net-core, I get the following `project.json`:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "ConsoleAppTest Console Application",
  "authors": [ "Nemo" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
  },

  "commands": {
    "ConsoleAppTest": "ConsoleAppTest"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
```

This project compiles and runs just fine when used by VS2015.
But as net-core point is cross-platform compatibility, I would like to restore and build it via dotcore cli (and for example, do CI builds on Travis-ci).
When running `dotnet restore` inside this project, I get the following error:

```
log  : Restoring packages for {my_path}\Projects\ConsoleAppTest\src\ConsoleAppTest\project.json...
error: System.Console 4.0.0-beta-23516 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Console on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x64.
error: System.Threading 4.0.11-beta-23516 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x64.
error: System.Dynamic.Runtime 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Dynamic.Runtime on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x64.
error: System.Linq.Expressions 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Linq.Expressions on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x64.
error: System.IO 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.IO on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x64.
error: System.Threading.Tasks 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.Tasks on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x64.
error: System.Text.Encoding 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Text.Encoding on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x64.
error: Some packages are not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0 (win7-x64).
error: System.Console 4.0.0-beta-23516 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Console on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x86.
error: System.Threading 4.0.11-beta-23516 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x86.
error: System.Dynamic.Runtime 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Dynamic.Runtime on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x86.
error: System.Linq.Expressions 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Linq.Expressions on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x86.
error: System.IO 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.IO on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x86.
error: System.Threading.Tasks 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.Tasks on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x86.
error: System.Text.Encoding 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Text.Encoding on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x86.
error: Some packages are not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0 (win7-x86).
info : Committing restore...
log  : Restore failed in 520ms.

Errors in {my_path}\Projects\ConsoleAppTest\src\ConsoleAppTest\project.json
    System.Console 4.0.0-beta-23516 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Console on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x64.
    System.Threading 4.0.11-beta-23516 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x64.
    System.Dynamic.Runtime 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Dynamic.Runtime on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x64.
    System.Linq.Expressions 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Linq.Expressions on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x64.
    System.IO 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.IO on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x64.
    System.Threading.Tasks 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.Tasks on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x64.
    System.Text.Encoding 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Text.Encoding on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x64.
    Some packages are not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0 (win7-x64).
    System.Console 4.0.0-beta-23516 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Console on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x86.
    System.Threading 4.0.11-beta-23516 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x86.
    System.Dynamic.Runtime 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Dynamic.Runtime on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x86.
    System.Linq.Expressions 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Linq.Expressions on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x86.
    System.IO 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.IO on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x86.
    System.Threading.Tasks 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.Tasks on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x86.
    System.Text.Encoding 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Text.Encoding on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win7-x86.
    Some packages are not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0 (win7-x86).

NuGet Config files used:
    {another_path}\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config

Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

The same error appears while attempting to dotnet restore it on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty in Travis CI, but except win7-x86 is replaced with Ubuntu.

#### Dotnet CLI -> VS2015

If I create a new project using dotnet new command, I get the following project.json:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "compilationOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
    },

    "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.0.0-rc2-23811"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnxcore50": { }
    }
}
```

This project compiles and runs just fine when run from `dotnet` command.
But I would like to make it work with VS2015 as it is very comfortable IDE – so I open `project.json` as a project, everything seems to be working (no conflicts or errors in dependencies shown).

I add commands entry to json: `“commands”: { “ConsoleAppTest2”: “ConsoleAppTest2”}` and hit CTRL+F5  - I am therefore greeted with following error:

```
System.IO.FileLoadExpection: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definiton does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetEntryPoint(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retMethod)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_EntryPoint()
```

I have just started working with net-core and have no clue how to solve this.
I fear it might have to do with VS2015 using old version of dotnet core ( while opening dotnet new created project, VS2015 output of restoring packages contains the following line:
`C:\Users\{user}\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2\bin\dnx.exe` ).
If this is of importance, I have installed dotnet cli from msi.install long after VS2015 was installed.

#### Stats

The stats I think may be useful:

**OS**: Windows 10 x64 En

**VS**: Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2 (I am up to date all suggested updates)

**Result of running `dnx --version`**:
    Microsoft .NET Execution environment
     Version:      1.0.0-rc1-16609
     Type:         CoreClr
     Architecture: x64
     OS Name:      Windows
     OS Version:   10.0
     Runtime Id:   win10-x64

**Result of running `where dnx`**:
    C:\Users{{user}}.dnx\runtimes\dnx-coreclr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update2\bin\dnx.exe

**Result of running `dnvm version`**: 1.0.0.rc1-15540

**Result of running `where dnvm`**:
    C:\Users{{user}}.dnx\bin\dnvm.cmd
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\dnvm.cmd

**Result of running `dotnet --version`**:
    .NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-beta-001598)

```
Product Information:
 Version:     1.0.0-beta-001598
 Commit Sha:  7582649f88

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.10586
 OS Platform: Windows
 Runtime Id:  win10-x64
```

**Result of running `where dotnet`**:
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\bin\dotnet.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions is correct. The tooling in VS is not up to date yet. Microsoft has a internal release of the visual studio tooling just two weeks ago for the dotnet CLI. A LOT has changed between RC1 (VS2015.2 dnx based tooling) and the new dotnet CLI which is not yet released.

Wait two weeks. RC2 is coming, most probably with tooling support.

Comment: Is there any way to get a preview of that release ?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/05/16/announcing-asp-net-core-rc2/
This has indeed fixed the issues.